# Feature not identified by the *Given* tag while running Cucumber BDD tests in Geb Framework (Groovy)

Tags: groovy, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, bdd, geb

I'm trying to perform the automation tests of a web application using Geb Framework with Cucumber. However, while running my first test I have stumbled upon a NullPointerException as soon as the program reaches the 'Given' tag. I have searched the Internet for clues but found no answers. I have also referred to both Geb and Cucumber documentations and found many examples of 'good practice' while making use of Cucumber, but every code example that I tried to adjust my code to and ran concluded in the same Null Pointer Exception.

A significant excerpt from my code is included below:

*test.groovy*

```
import geb.Browser
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys

import static cucumber.api.groovy.EN.*

browser = new Browser()
browser.go "/"


Given(~'Home page is opened') {
    browser.to HomePage
    assert browser.at(HomePage)
}

When(~'Add offer button is clicked') {
    HomePage.addOfferLink
}

[...]
```

*GebConfig.groovy*

```
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver

/**
 * Created by apoteralowicz on 2015-08-24.
 */

def newDriver
    driver =
    {
        newDriver = new ChromeDriver();
        newDriver.manage().window().maximize();
        return newDriver;
    }
System.setProperty('webdriver.chrome.driver', 'src/binary/chromedriver.exe')
```

*HomePage.groovy*

```
import geb.Page

/**
 * Created by apoteralowicz on 2015-08-24.
 */
class HomePage extends Page {
    static url = "/";
    static at = { waitFor { title.contains('Home') } };
    static content = {

    /*Menu tab links*/
    HomeLink(to: HomePage) {
        $('.menuBarNav').find('a[href="/"]')
    };
    IntercityLink(to: IntercityPage) {
        $('.menuBarNav').find('a[href="/LiftOffer/CityOffers/0?pageSize=5"]')
    };
    EntriesLink(to: EntriesPage) {
        $('.menuBarNav').find('a[href="/LiftOffer/MyEntriesOffers/1?pageSize=5"]')
    };

    CreateDropdownButton(to: '#') {
        $('#createButton')
    };
    addOfferLink(to: AddOfferPage) {
        $('.dropdown-menu').find('a[href="/LiftOffer/Create/1"]')
    };
    addRequestLink(to: AddRequestPage) {
        $('.dropdown-menu').find('a[href="/LiftOffer/Create/2"]')
    };

    SearchLink(to: SearchOffersPage) {
        $('.menuBarNav').find('a[href="/LiftOffer/Search?type=1&pageSize=5"]')
    };
    MessageboxLink(to: MailboxPage) {
        $('.menuBarNav').find('a[href="/LiftOffer/MessageBox"]')
    };

    /*Additional Buttons*/
    ShowOffersButton(to: SearchOffersPage) {
        $('a[href="/LiftOffer/Search/?type=1"]')
    };
    ShowRequestsButton(to: SearchRequestsPage) {
        $('a[href="/LiftOffer/Search/?type=2"]')
    };
    }
}
```

*testScript.feature*

```
Feature: new lift offer creation
  As an user
  I want to create a lift offer for people
  So that I could inform people that I am going somewhere and I have free seats available

  Scenario:
    Given Home page is opened
    When Add Offer button is clicked
    Then User can input some data into the Create New Lift Offer form
    And User can save the offer
```

*Exact error*

```
Starting ChromeDriver (v2.11.298604 (75ea2fdb5c87f133a8e1b8da16f6091fb7d5321e)) on port 40529
Only local connections are allowed.
Caught: java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at cucumber.api.groovy.EN.Given(EN.java:27)
    at cucumber.api.groovy.EN$Given.callStatic(Unknown Source)
    at testScript1.run(testScript1.groovy:15)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

To sum up, I assume the problem is that somehow the *Given* feature is not identified correctly, but I have no idea why and thus I came to ask here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know now that I should have added a separate class to run the tests.

```
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber
import org.junit.runner.RunWith

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features = "src", format = ["pretty", "html:build/reports/tests/cucumber/html", "json:build/reports/tests/cucumber.json"])
class RunTests {
}
```